# sqlite on portable class library

Tags: windows-8, sqlite, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to use Sqlite inside a portable class library ? I nedd to share code between a win store app as well as a web application , both of which uses sqlite as DB. I am stuck in adding windows reference to my PCL..

Comment: possible duplicate of [using SQLite inside portable class library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699544/using-sqlite-inside-portable-class-library)

Answer (score 0):

In short no, from what I've read, this question provides a more detailed explanation:

[using SQLite inside portable class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699544/using-sqlite-inside-portable-class-library)