# Can a class be removed by code

Tags: c#, sqlite, portable-class-library

I have a query whether there is any sensible (pinch of salt needed here) mechanism to 'remove' a class from my codebase.
I'm not trying to delete a .cs file here, I'm trying to kind of 'null out' a class.

I'm looking for something which does something along the lines of 'un-declaring' a class definition.

The reason for this slightly odd request idea is that I have a PCL with some shared entities. These entities are used by SQLite and in the PCL library I've defined the SQLite `[PrimaryKeyAttribute]` property so that I can mark the entities PKs.

In my consuming library I have SQLite for Windows Runtime installed and 'sqlite-net' for the linq like wrapper. It's in this wrapper that the `[PrimaryKeyAttribute]` is defined.

What I was hoping to do was define the `[PrimaryKeyAttribute]` class as below in the PCL library:

```
namespace SQLite
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class PrimaryKeyAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
}
```

But the problem with that is that it's overwritten by the same definition in the consuming library. Things work happily if I comment out the attribute from the definition in the consuming library, but as soon as I (or someone else) updates the sqlite-net package we're going to hit a load of issues as the data access will fall over.

I suppose I'm looking for a kind of 'do not compile' flag of some form which I can apply to code in a different file. Any ideas/thoughts on this one?

Comment: What does 'PCL' stand for? BTW: Despite the long explanation it is still unclear what the *original* problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, a PCL is a portable class library (we are sharing classes between a windows store app, and a web app).
The original problem is that in this shared assembly, the entity classes need to be decorated with the PrimaryKeyAttribute, but that class is not defined until the consuming assembly. As a result I can't use the property without defining it in the PCL. If I define it in the PCL, it is effectively re-defined in the consuming library  .

Comment: Still not clear. Why is this attribute defined in the consuming library? Isn't it supposed to be defined by SQLite?

Comment: Yes, SQLite is included in the consuming library which is where it's defined. SQLite cannot be included in the PCL unfortunately.

Comment: But that means that your problem isn't a "redefinition" of the class. This isn't happening, because the classes are still in two different assemblies, hence distinct. Your problem is that you are using a class that is unknown by SQLite.

Comment: Well, redefinition may be a bit inaccurate as you say. What happens if that if I define the attribute class in the PCL in the SQLite namespace and comment out the same definition in the SQLite code, things work happily. If I let SQLite define the same attribute class, then it sees the two classes as distinct and chooses the one defined in it's own assembly.

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes a bit more sense. Why can't you reference SQLite from the PCL?

Comment: I believe because it's a native DLL under the hood. I did some searching and came across threads like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699544/using-sqlite-inside-portable-class-library

Comment: Specifically for sqlite-net - you can look at separating it out into a PCL and native part. That's what I've done within mvvmcross - see the two parts in: PCL - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/Sqlite/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite/BaseClasses.cs and platform: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/Sqlite/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite/SharedFile/SQLiteNet.cs - the attributes are in the PCL part

Comment: @Stuart yeah that's what I have at the moment (the attribute defined in the PCL) but as you've done I've removed the attribute from the sqlite-net code. What I'm worried about is that someone new comes in and updates sqlite-net without understanding the need to ditch the attribute.

Comment: they'll get a compile error when they do - so just put a comment near your class for them to find when that happens. Also I talked with Frank last month and we will do the PCL/non-PCL split 'soon' - see https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/135

Comment: Oddly, I don't get a compile error when I define the attribute in both assemblies, sqlite just doesn't see the property 'correctly' and thinks all my entities have no primary key. I then get a bunch of runtime errors throughout my DAL :(