# Common interface for SQLite to both WinRT and Windows Phone apps when using Portable Class Libraries

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, portable-class-library

This is to essentially reuse a lot of code written for a WinRT app for a Windows Phone 8 app that calls the DB layer. I intend to port some of the DB access calls from the WinRT app to a shared Portable Class library, but SQLite(even the .NET plugin) cannot be used directly here, or imported from a non-PCL package.

One way that seems feasible to me is to create a PCL for SQLite that would have an interface, which would load up platform dependencies using constructor injection, and then reference this SQLite PCL inside the PCL to be shared between WinPhone and WinRT. Could someone point out potential shortcomings to this?

Also, I'm not developing on MVVMCross.

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess one of the shortcomings is that the wrapper should not contain any logic or else you will have to duplicate it for each platform. Other then that you will have a higher level of complexity and may have to first introduce the principles behind dependency injection.

Did you see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699544/using-sqlite-inside-portable-class-library) on SO?

Further there is an article on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh335063.aspx) describing how to use pcl and dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go for using the MvvmCross plugins. We are currently using them on a project which does not use MvvmCross as a whole.

Very easy to integrate using IOC / Di containers.

[MvvmCross Plugins Link](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Plugins/Cirrious)

The biggest thing to note is you do NOT need to be using MvvmCross to use the plugins.